# Problems with script erasing software

Tags: powershell

I found the following script which was supposed to only create a restore point, clean temps, Disk cleanup and disk optimize. The only issues is that when I ran it, it erased all the software I had. Luckily I had a restore point but I can't seems to figure out why it did that. For learning purposes I would like for someone to point out the mistake within it to understand it better.

```
# 1.creating the restore point 
Checkpoint-Computer -Description "Weekly Maintanence" -RestorePointType "MODIFY_SETTINGS"
Write-Host "System Restore Point created successfully"

#3.Delete Temp Files
   
    $objShell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application   
    $objFolder = $objShell.Namespace(0xA)   
      
    $temp = get-ChildItem "env:\TEMP"   
    $temp2 = $temp.Value   
      
    $WinTemp = "c:\Windows\Temp\*"   
  
# Remove temp files located in "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp"   
    write-Host "Removing Junk files in $temp2." -ForegroundColor Magenta    
    Remove-Item -Recurse  "$temp2\*" -Force -Verbose   
     
# Remove Windows Temp Directory (Folder)    
    write-Host "Removing Junk files in $WinTemp." -ForegroundColor Green   
    Remove-Item -Recurse $WinTemp -Force    
      
#5. Running Disk Clean up Tool    
    write-Host " Running Windows disk Clean up Tool" -ForegroundColor Cyan   
 cleanmgr /sagerun:1 | out-Null  

    $([char]7)   
    Sleep 1    
    $([char]7)   
    Sleep 1        
    
    write-Host "Clean Up Task completed !" "
```

Comment: Where did you find the script? How about asking the author for help?

Comment: The script is from a "script community library" which is supposed to be "Secure". The author has not updated this script lately and also I can't contact the author through the platform

Comment: It doesn't look malicious.  I can only see it removing items from 2 temp locations and running cleanmgr.  Do you keep all your software in temp folders?

Comment: I do not keep my software on temp folders. This script literally deleted everything including microsoft store, mail app, calculator, every single piece of software.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have your programs installed in one of the TEMP folders this cleans up, your issue isn't with PowerShell or your code. It's likely due to however `cleanmgr` had `/sageset` saved before (with `cleanmgr /sageset:1` or `cleanmgr /tuneup:1`) or there was some issue with `cleanmgr`. `cleanmgr /sagerun:1` will run with whatever settings were previously saved in `/sageset:1` before.

---

<s>The only thing I'm not clear on is this piece does</s> ASCII Code 07 is the `Bell` character, this gives the window attention (makes the taskbar icon flash) when `[char]7` is written to the console.

```
$([char]7)
```

Comment: I do not keep my software on temp folders. This script literally deleted everything including microsoft store, mail app, calculator, every single piece of software. I tested on a few test workstations and it did the same on all.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is that `%TEMP%` was set to something other than `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Temp`, and that location housed several of your installed programs. If that's not it, the only other destructive thing I see in this script is the use of `cleanmgr /sagerun:1`. If this is happening on multiple workstations, I would double check to see if you are deploying a `cleanmgr` configuration that might explain this.